# Converting a switch statement to ternary statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I'm looking to convert the following code block below to a single line of code using only ternary statements:

```
switch(true)
{
    case (cond_1_bool):
        val_res = (cond_1_1_bool || cond_1_2_bool) ? res_1_1: res_1_2;
        break;

    default:
        val_res = res_2_1;
}
```

How can I do this?!

Comment: I don't think you can convert it to "a" ternary statement - at minimum you'd need two ternaries since there are three possible results (though as some of the answers below show you _can_ do it on one line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
val_res = cond_1_bool ? ((cond_1_1_bool || cond_1_2_bool) ? res_1_1 : res_1_2) : res_2_1;
```

Comment: @ChuckUgwuh not at all

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess

```
val_res = (cond_1_bool)? ((cond_1_1_bool || cond_1_2_bool) ? res_1_1: res_1_2): res_2_1;
```

Comment: This works too. I selected Givi's one because it came earlier (albeit one minute only). Cheers.